# Is Virtual memory infinite?

Tags: memory

I have been asked in an interview if virtual memory is infinite? I answered saying that it is not infinite. Then the interviewer asked the explanation and what I suggested was that in windows we do have a manual way to configure virtual memory to a certain limit.

I would like to know if Virtual memory is really Infinite?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**First of all, forget the idea that virtual memory is limited by the size of pointers on your machine.**

Virtual memory limits are not the same as addressing space. You can address more virtual memory than is available in your pointer-based address space using paging.

- Virtual memory upper limits are set by the
  OS: for example, on 32-bit Windows
  the limit is 16TB, and on 64-bit
  Windows the limit is 256TB.
- Virtual memory is also physically limited by the
  available disc space.

For an excellent overview, which addresses various misconceptions, see the following:

**http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx**

Comment: Yes @stusmith i think you are right about You can address more virtual memory than is available in your pointer-based ,and it is whole idea of using virtual memory.

Comment: Virtual memory is not exactly limited by disk space, it can be allocated but not mapped, so-called "reserved virtual memory". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx and MEM_RESERVE for explanation.

Comment: HI, if so, why I still get out of memory error in a 4 GB ram with enough disk space?

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else then virtual memory is going to be limited by the amount of disk space available, this sadly is far from infinite.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, the size of virtual memory is limited by the size of pointers on given platform (unless it has near/far pointers and non-flat memory model). For example, you cannot address more than about 2^32 (4GB) of memory using single 32-bit pointer.

In practice, the virtual memory must be backed up with something eventually -- like a pagefile on disk -- so the size of storage enforces a more practical limit.

Comment: Sorry, that's just wrong. Look up "PAE" (Physical Address Extension) for example.

Comment: @stusmith : A PAE-enabled Linux-kernel requires that the CPU also support PAE. So, it is limited by the computer architecture, right?

Comment: @logic_max: Yes, but a 32-bit Intel chip is capable of supporting PAE. Maybe a better way of putting it is: it is the lowest value of [chip support, OS limit, disk space]. Usually that lowest value is disk space.

Comment: @stusmith I don't think that ARM, PowerPC, MIPS, or many other CPUs have PAE.  Neither do older **x86** CPUs.  There is no right answer to this poor question.  In fact, depending on how you count (for the system, for a process), the answer is different, but still not infinite.  Down-vote anyone who says it is infinite.

Comment: It is also not true that everything **must** be backed by disk.  A large *zero initialized* array can all be backed by a single page of zeros (typically 4-8k).  Any read from any address will show zero.  On the first write to a page, a fault happens and then the page is allocated (needs disk or memory) and remapped.  This can allow large sparse arrays.

Comment: The sum of the virtual address spaces of *all* the processes running at once can be larger than what the 'user pointer' register can address - since the 'process id' is effectively part of the virtual address. In some cases these "process-unique" addresses actually point to the same PM (e.g. shared libraries, data shared after fork() ) - but even allowing for that, it's possible for the total amount of truly distinct VM pages to exceed what one process can address.

Comment: But each process see the 2^32 separately , right ? I mean the limitation should theoretically be summarizing the virtual memory for all process, i.e. more than 2^32*num_process

Answer (score 0):

You were right to say, no, it's not infinite. 
Addressable virtual memory is limited by architecture address space.
For further info see [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Answer (score 0):

The size of virtual storage is limited by the addressing scheme of the computer system and by the amount of secondary memory available and not by actual number of main memory locations.

For example :- Even if you had 20 TB of secondary memory, it doesn't mean that virtual memory can be 20TB. It is restricted by your computer architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Virtual memory is the summation of RAM and available hard disk space in most cases. As the summation is a countable number, it can't be infinity.

Comment: `Virtual memory is the summation of RAM and available hard disk space in most cases` Wrong. RAM is physical memory, not virtual

Comment: @raoul: i didn't say ram is virtual memory.

Comment: you clearly said `Virtual memory is the summation of RAM and available hard disk space in most cases`.

Comment: @raoul: i meant `virtual memory = RAM + HDD space` in most cases. sorry if my english implies something else.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but it I'm telling you that this is wrong.

Comment: @raoul: i think i'm right. check the image & caption in 'virtual memory' wikipedia page given in your answer: `Virtual memory combines active RAM and inactive memory in disk form into a large range of contiguous addresses.`

Comment: @Raoul let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1211/discussion-between-donotalo-and-raoul)

Comment: @Raoul sorry for being late, but what Donotalo wants to say is virtual memory can have max space of RAM and hard disk combined, not calling them virtual memory.