# Is there any limit on a process’s virtual memory? If so what?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I faced this question in my interview, I answered that, there is no limit, as virtual memory itself imaginary thing, so we don't have any limit.

But I don't understand any proper answer by googling.

Kindly help me out in this and explain the memory limit of virtual memory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Googling title gives: 'About 1,550,000 results'.  So ' don't find any valid arguments related to that by googling' means something is wrong with Google, or something is wrong with OP.  Essentially, OP, I don't believe you.

Comment: @MartinJames, googling gives more results, but i'm not getting what i exactly need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608820/is-virtual-memory-infinite

Comment: Ok, Sridar, what do you need in result no. 1,550,001?

Comment: I mean, I'm guessing a unique answer that you can copy/paste into your assignment,

Answer (score 0):

The maximum theoretical size for virtual memory is given by the size of a pointer.  The largest number that can be represented by the pointer is the maximum theoretical size of virtual memory.  The units are the minimal addressable memory unit (typically bytes).

Real operating systems sometimes impose additional restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of restrictions on virtual memory.

1. The address range of the underlying hardware.
2. Any subdivisions of the address space. Some ranges may be reserved (for example, System and User address spaces) Some may be invalid altogether. Example: VAX divides the 32-bit address evenly into 2 user spaces, a system space, and a reserved (unusable space).
3. Limits the operating system imposes on page table size. Must system have a parameter and/or account setting limiting this.
4. The size of the page file.